# Can't see action clip in Action Editor after animating a certain things

Tags: animation

[image]

I have put 2 keyframes to animate the Energy of my light source. The action clip "Lamp.001Action.001" shows up under the Outliner and keyframes shows up in the Dopesheet. However when I switch to Action Editor I could not see "Lamp.001Action.001" in the action selector

When I was animating Location Rotation Scale with `I` key the new action clip can be found as expected, so why not light's energy? I am going to link this light to another .blend file so I need to make sure I can access the action clip to use it in other file's NLA editor.

Comment: But the deepest selectable is "BigLightLamp"(Orange light bulb) and not the actual light data (grey light bulb/point light icon) inside it. So is that means the action resides deeper than the object level cannot be accessed?

Comment: Oh Ok, the action editor only shows actions on objects, not data.  The action name in the outliner is the one you need to append / link to from another file.  If you are into scripting it can be found via python console, by selecting object with lamp data and entering `C.object.data.animation_data.action.name`  or `D.lamps["Lamp.001"].animation_data.action.name`